# what is mean? "de_put: entry ip_tables_names already free!"

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

When I attempt to start or stop iptables (/etc/init.d/iptables start) in Debian, I'm getting this error: `de_put: entry ip_tables_names already free!` I don't think iptables is working. What does this error mean?

- can't /etc/init.d/iptable stop/start

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what this error means, but you can use:

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep ip_tables
```

to check that iptables is loaded. Also, you can apply some rules manually for testing. For example, you can do:

```
$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

This should drop all outgoing requests. You can allow again by:

```
$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**However, this should be tested only in a testing environment and not in production.**